# How acquire Census same-sex with children data - separate variables but reports include combo

Tags: r, tidycensus

I use the `tidycensus` R package all the time and cannot figure out how articles like this one used the Census 2019 1-year ACS estimates to produce stats like:

"**In 2019, 22.5% of female same-sex couple households had children under 18 present, compared with 6.6% of male same-sex couple households.**"
-- [from this Census article][1]

The Census variables available for same-sex households do not include children. Is there some way to intersect variables like these with children-specifying variables?

### Same-sex variables (not many)

```
library(tidycensus)
library(dplyr)
#### Census API key
## Only need this line because API key stored in .Renviron
## If not stored, get Census API key at http://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html then run
## census_api_key("PLACE CENSUS KEY HERE", install = TRUE)
## per https://rdrr.io/cran/tidycensus/man/census_api_key.html
Sys.getenv("CENSUS_API_KEY")
vars19 <- load_variables(2019, dataset = "acs1", cache = TRUE)         
vars19 %>% dplyr::filter(grepl('SAME-SEX', toupper(label)))                             
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   name       label                                                                                             concept                                                          
   <chr>      <chr>                                                                                             <chr>                                                            
 1 B09019_011 Estimate!!Total:!!In households:!!Same-sex spouse                                                 HOUSEHOLD TYPE (INCLUDING LIVING ALONE) BY RELATIONSHIP          
 2 B09019_013 Estimate!!Total:!!In households:!!Same-sex unmarried partner                                      HOUSEHOLD TYPE (INCLUDING LIVING ALONE) BY RELATIONSHIP          
 3 B11009_004 Estimate!!Total:!!Married couple households:!!Same-sex:                                           COUPLED HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE                                       
 4 B11009_005 Estimate!!Total:!!Married couple households:!!Same-sex:!!Male householder and male spouse         COUPLED HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE                                       
 5 B11009_006 Estimate!!Total:!!Married couple households:!!Same-sex:!!Female householder and female spouse     COUPLED HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE                                       
 6 B11009_009 Estimate!!Total:!!Cohabiting couple households:!!Same-sex:                                        COUPLED HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE                                       
 7 B11009_010 Estimate!!Total:!!Cohabiting couple households:!!Same-sex:!!Male householder and male partner     COUPLED HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE                                       
 8 B11009_011 Estimate!!Total:!!Cohabiting couple households:!!Same-sex:!!Female householder and female partner COUPLED HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE                                       
 9 B12504_005 Estimate!!Total:!!Male:!!Married, spouse present:!!Same-sex spouse                                MEDIAN DURATION OF CURRENT MARRIAGE IN YEARS BY SEX BY MARITAL S…
10 B12504_011 Estimate!!Total:!!Female:!!Married, spouse present:!!Same-sex spouse                              MEDIAN DURATION OF CURRENT MARRIAGE IN YEARS BY SEX BY MARITAL S…
```

### An example of children-specifying variables.

```
> vars19 %>% dplyr::filter(concept == 'SUBFAMILY TYPE BY PRESENCE OF OWN CHILDREN UNDER 18 YEARS')
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  name       label                                                                         concept                                                  
  <chr>      <chr>                                                                         <chr>                                                    
1 B11013_001 Estimate!!Total:                                                              SUBFAMILY TYPE BY PRESENCE OF OWN CHILDREN UNDER 18 YEARS
2 B11013_002 Estimate!!Total:!!Married-couple subfamily:                                   SUBFAMILY TYPE BY PRESENCE OF OWN CHILDREN UNDER 18 YEARS
3 B11013_003 Estimate!!Total:!!Married-couple subfamily:!!With own children under 18 years SUBFAMILY TYPE BY PRESENCE OF OWN CHILDREN UNDER 18 YEARS
4 B11013_004 Estimate!!Total:!!Married-couple subfamily:!!No own children under 18 years   SUBFAMILY TYPE BY PRESENCE OF OWN CHILDREN UNDER 18 YEARS
5 B11013_005 Estimate!!Total:!!Mother-child subfamily                                      SUBFAMILY TYPE BY PRESENCE OF OWN CHILDREN UNDER 18 YEARS
6 B11013_006 Estimate!!Total:!!Father-child subfamily                                      SUBFAMILY TYPE BY PRESENCE OF OWN CHILDREN UNDER 18 YEARS
```

[1]: [https://www.census.gov/library/stories/2020/09/fifteen-percent-of-same-sex-couples-have-children-in-their-household.html#:~:text=Fifteen%20percent%20(14.7%25)%20of,CPS](https://www.census.gov/library/stories/2020/09/fifteen-percent-of-same-sex-couples-have-children-in-their-household.html#:%7E:text=Fifteen%20percent%20(14.7%25)%20of,CPS))%20data%20released%20this%20week.

Comment: The article notes the data they used was from a Current Population Survey supplement on fertility https://www.census.gov/data/datasets/time-series/demo/cps/cps-supp_cps-repwgt/cps-fertility.html. Since it's not ACS or 10 year census, you won't be able to access it with `tidycensus`. You can still download the data direct from the website, though of course it won't be in the wonderfully easy to use format that `tidycensus` provides.

Comment: You can do it with the ACS PUMS and `get_pums()` in tidycensus.  Read through here for some info on how to get started: https://walker-data.com/census-r/introduction-to-census-microdata.html